# Place element to top inside navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to decorate my navbar so that it looks a bit nicer, I use bootstrapv4 as base and i just want to add 2 "Stripes" on top of the navbar, but for some reason bootstrap centers my decorations, something I want to prevent.

Here is my code (a bit simplified)

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-green">
  <div class="navbar-top-bg"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-top-fg"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-top-bg {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(67, 107, 65, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 111111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(87, 136, 89, 0.4);
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar-top-fg {
  position: relative;
  content: "";
  width: 288px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(40px) rotateX(-16deg);
  transform: perspective(40px) rotateX(-16deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1111111;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.4);*/
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(65, 100, 62);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(65, 100, 62);
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar-green {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  background: rgba(37, 48, 27, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(39, 41, 37, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(39, 41, 37, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(39, 41, 37, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(39, 41, 37, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(39, 41, 37, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(39, 41, 37, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#25301b', endColorstr='#79bd64', GradientType=0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(91, 115, 89, 0.08) !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

As you can see, the 2 green stripes are in the center of the navbar (vertically) but i want them on top (to see that layout just remove the `navbar` and `navbar-expand-lg` classes) but i also want to use the common "navbar" features to add links and so on.

Here also a link to jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Insax/apzb42b9/

Comment: use top:0 on elements you want at top

Comment: use align-self:flex-start;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` on both parts of the "stripe" and use `top: 0` to position them to the top. Use `left: 0` and `right: 0` to center them.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/apzb42b9/3/)

```
.navbar-top-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(67, 107, 65, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 111111;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(87, 136, 89, 0.4);
}

.navbar-top-fg {
  width: 288px;
  height: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(40px) rotateX(-16deg);
  transform: perspective(40px) rotateX(-16deg);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1111111;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(234, 234, 234, 0.4);*/
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(65, 100, 62);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(65, 100, 62);
}

.navbar-top-bg,
.navbar-top-fg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```